# Can a dropdown menu be editable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown menu in that I'm displaying 2-3 customer ids. Now,user wants to enter a customer id which doesn't appear in the drop down menu. Is it possible to make the drop down menu editable ?

Comment: An editable dropdown is called a **combobox**. Now you have a new search keyword ;) This is by the way not specifically related to JSP since all it basically does is generating/serving HTML/CSS which you in turn still have to write in the template yourself. Your problem is more in the HTML area. I'll edit the necessary tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wondering if a `<select>`-input can be made editable, the answer is, *no*, (not without some cleaver Javascripting).

You could for instance try out one of these:

- http://chakrabarty.com/combobox.html
- http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/form_widget_editable_select/form_widget_editable_select.html
- http://coffeescripter.com/code/editable-select/

(All found by googling on *html editable select*)

Comment: That particular one has the annoying property that backspace doesn't work -- it's not really a textbox, it's just using keystrokes to add letters.

Comment: Updated the answer, have a look at the second link. :)

Comment: yes I'm using <select> I didn't understand in the second link you mentioned. please help!!!

Comment: i see another posting like this :                               <div>
  <input id="mySelectInput type="text" onchange="filterSelect()"/><br/>
  <select id="mySelect" size="6">
    <!-- array of options -->
  </select>
</div>
but how do you write filterSelect() ?

Comment: aioobe- here it is- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454770/is-an-editable-select-box-the-right-way

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I suppose it just walks through the options of the select and filters out the relevant ones based on the text-field. Can't give you any specific javascript suggestions though.

Answer (score 2):

I made a complete working example of atom217's code (he's missing the function)

```
<script>
    function E(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
    function changeit(drp,txf)
    {
        dd = E(drp);
        E(txf).value = dd.options[ dd.selectedIndex ].text;
    }
</script>

<div style="position:relative; top:0px; left:0px;" >

<input type="text" id="TextField" style="width:140px; position:absolute; top:1px; left:1px; z-index:2; border:none;" />

<select id="DropDown" onchange="changeit('DropDown','TextField')" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 165px;" >
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">-- Select Column --</option>
    <option> example option one </option>
    <option> example option two </option>
</select>

</div>
```

Just tried it. Works on my 4 target browsers. (I was also looking for this)

Comment: just a comment. if you have many, add a `<br>` between them, or they will overlap

Answer (score 0):

you can try doing that using CSS

try following [code(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/QEVXK/)

```
    <div style="position: absolute;top: 32px; left: 430px;" id="outerFilterDiv">
<input name="filterTextField" type="text" id="filterTextField" tabindex="2"  style="width: 140px;
    position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; z-index: 2;border:none;" />
        <div style="position: absolute;" id="filterDropdownDiv">
<select name="filterDropDown" id="filterDropDown" tabindex="1000"
    onchange="DropDownTextToBox(this,'filterTextField');" style="position: absolute;
    top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 165px;">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">-- Select Column Name --</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: it's now available in HTML5:

```
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp