# How to add input type=text filed inside select control PHP?

Tags: php, html

I want to add input filed inside my select control to let user to insert search text if he doesn't choose any option does anyone has any idea, this is my code?

```
    <select name="select" id="selectId">
<?php 

foreach($locations as $location){
echo "<option value=''.$location['location_id']."'>".$location['name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: First of all, this question should be tagged [tag:html]

Comment: You have to choose an alternative as it is not possible to make a select's option editable without javascript.
You can either use javascript/jquery to create a combobox with editable value (look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4831619/2005057) or put an `<input type="text" ...` under your select.

Comment: Thx @FrankBessou I will see it

Comment: No this answer doesn't help me at all sorry

Comment: where is the issue in the code ? any errors ?

Comment: I did it somehow with Jquery but now my problem is how to to stylize just option inside select